# has_many :through seems wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A "Project" has_many "ProjectAdmins" and many "ProjectCollaborators".

I've set this up as `has_many through` relationship:

1. Project - name:string
2. Users - email:string
3. ProjectAdmins - project:references, user:references
4. ProjectCollaborators - project:references, user:references

Are my relationships correct in my models? It seems wrong to list `has_many :users` twice.

**Project**

```
has_many :project_admins
has_many :project_collaborators
has_many :users, through: :project_admins
has_many :users, through: :project_collaborators
```

**Users**

```
has_many :project_admins
has_many :project_collaborators
has_many :projects, through: project_admins
has_many :projects, through: project_collaborators
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use your associations.

If a user can not be a collaborator and an admin for the same project at the same time, you could merge the two models to a single model and determine 'admin' or 'collaborator' with a `user_type` kind of attribute, or with a specific role.

It seems to me a decision that should be driven by your data.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because has_many, belongs_to, etc methods simply add a bunch of readers and writers to your model. When you try to create an association with the same name, those methods will be overridden.

I would approach this problem differently.

There are several options.

1. A simpler solution would be to use only one `ProjectUser` model that would have a `role:string` (or `:references` + a separate `Role` model, if you'd like to keep things normalised) field to your User model. Add a bunch of convenience methods, like `#admin?` and `#collaborator?`. And you're all set.
2. Or you could go with [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) (single table inheritance). Create a base class `ProjectUser project:references user:references` and inherit `ProjectAdmin` and `ProjectCollaborator` from it. Alternatively, since `ProjectAdmin` is probably always a collaborator, you could inherit it from `ProjectCollaborator`.

Basically, both solutions will give you the same results. But I'd say, the second one is better if you need to have different methods for different ProjectUser types.